# How to write a formula to total only some values once Y/N is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that has a column for 'amounts owing' 'due date' 'paid Y/N' and then a total at the bottom.  What I'd like is to put a formula in that deducts the 'amount' from the 'total' when the 'paid Y/N' column = Y.  I want my total to show just outstanding amounts.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sumifs to sum the amount column when the Paid column = N

```
=sumifs(AmoundColumn,PaidColumn,"N")
```

[image]

Comment: if that solves your issue, please accept the answer as explained in the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend that you use PivotTable, no matter how the original data changes, you only need to refresh the data, the content of the PivotTable will correspond to the update.

Here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell `O33`:

  `=SUM(O27:O31)`
- Use this formula in cell `Q33`:

  `=O33-SUMPRODUCT((Q27:Q31="N")*(O27:O31))`

**N.B.**

- *If you are looking for only an outstanding amount, then you may use this in cell `Q35`.*

  ```
  =SUM(O27:O31)-SUMPRODUCT((Q27:Q31="N")*(O27:O31))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as neede.*